# Wifi access point "Authentication problem" "password may be incorrect"

Tags: wifi, wireless, dhcp, android, dns

I just mixed these 3 tutorials (first that one : https://thepi.io/how-to-use-your-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-access-point/ , then these to fix problems : https://learn.pi-supply.com/make/how-to-setup-a-wireless-access-point-on-the-raspberry-pi/ and https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#ap-config ) in order to get a wifi AP running isolated from the internet. (So I stopped at step5 of the turotial)

I have `hostapd` and `dnsmasq` working if I manually assign

```
ifconfig wlan0 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

at each reboot (don't know why it isn't automatically established by reading my conf files but whatever)

However from an android phone side, I get authentication problem errors when connecting, even though I ensured by entering the SSID's pass in clear text, that it matched with the one I wrote in the conf file. Pass does is equal or longer than 8chars.

Things I still don't understand though is the output of # `systemctl status dnsmasq` :

output :

```
using nameserver 192.168.1.1#53
read /etc/hosts - 4 addresses
```

But :

1. in all the confs I set up the interface `wlan0` at `192.168.0.1`, so is there nothing to worry and `192.168.1.1` is the "overall" local subnetwork ?
2. Also when `cat`ing the `/etc/hosts` file I don't have anything else meaningful than `127.0.0.1`, is it normal?
3. And finally to get `dnsmasq` `active(running)` I had to hardcode `port=5353` in one of the confs, otherwise `systemctl status` was telling me the service wasn't running because there was a conflict with port 53. So why, now that it is running, I see the port 53 instead of 5353 ??

Comment: *"there was a conflict with port 53"* -> The only thing port 53 is used for is DNS, so this implies you already have a DNS server running...

Comment: *"when cating the /etc/hosts file I don't have anything else meaningful than 127.0.0.1, is it normal?"* -- That's how it is stock.  See `man 5 hosts`.

Comment: thank you, the debian image is fresh and I installed nothing except this service I'm trying to get working, is there a way to tell if debian spins up its own DNS server ? this https://askubuntu.com/questions/191226/dnsmasq-failed-to-create-listening-socket-for-port-53-address-already-in-use was my precise bug with port 53, fixed by adding the line `port=5353` to /etc/dnsmasq.conf

Comment: I notice the top answer there mentions the same issue ("Check what's listening on port 53...").   Note that while `dnsmasq` also does DHCP server stuff (which you probably want), a DNS server on a network with two nodes is pointless.